# Every mere proposition is a set?

Tags: proof-explanation, homotopy-type-theory

In the HoTT Book, lemma 3.3.4 states that "every mere proposition is a set", where a mere proposition is a type $A$ such that $IsProp(A) = \prod_{x,y: A}(x=_Ay)$ holds, and a set is a type $A$ such that $IsSet(A) = \prod_{x,y:A} IsProp(x=_Ay)$ holds.

The proof of this lemma starts with "Fix $x:A$ [insert proof].", but never discharges the $x:A$ (as far as I can see).

So in fact, what the proof does is exhibit an element of type $\prod_{x:A}( isProp(A)\to IsSet(A))$, in other words of type $A\to isProp(A)\to IsSet(A)$ : as far as I can see, this not enough to get an element of type $isProp(A) \to IsSet(A)$ (without excluded middle) : am I missing something ?

If not, how can one fix the proof ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does discharge $x$. The statement being proved is $\prod_{x, y: A} \prod_{p, q: x = y} p = q$ (i.e. $\text{IsSet} A$) under the assumption of $f: \text{IsProp} A$. Along the way, the statement $\prod_{y, z: A} \prod_{p: y = z} p = g(y)^{-1} \cdot g(z)$ is proved, but then it's instantiated with $y := x$ and $z := y$ for the last line.

Comment: Ah right, I had actually misread that bit (because I actually got the proof from an online document, so I went to see in the book and the proof looked the same and so I thought they were the same, but the mistake is in the online document, not the book). Thank you !

Answer (score -3):

We can think of a proposition multiple ways:

We can think of a proposition of a statement that is either true or false

An example of a statement:

> Peter is eating

This whole statement is either true or false.

Next we can also see this as a proposition composed of one single statement without using any logical connectives.

For example

> Let $Q$ denote the proposition for the statement "Peter is drinking"
>   This single proposition can be seen as the truth table of possible combinations of $Q$ being a single proposition that is not a composition of other propositions.

Truth table of Q, with on the left the given input values and on the right the result of the proposition.

[image: the input for q on the left and de outcome on the right.]

Next we can use these non composed propositions in combination with our logical connectives to build more complex statements. This can either be by connecting the $Q$ in different ways or by using other defined statements.
For example

> We compose the following statement
>   "Peter is drinking **and** Peter is **not** drinking."
>   to be the proposition.
>
> $Q \land \neg(Q)$
>   We can also define it with another Letter to denote this statement.

Notice we still are using one "building block" proposition. That is how we defined Q. Yet by using the *and* connective and *the negation* we now have a whole different outcome for each combination we originally assign Q to be. This new statement will always be false regardless of the value of the non composed statement of $Q$

Thus we can conclude we have two different composed propositions:

> Q as a proposition composed of one single proposition.
>   $Q \land \neg(Q)$ as a proposition composed Q connected to negation of Q using the and connective to connect them $Q$ with $\neg(Q)$. And using $\neg$ to negate the $Q$

This will have the following truth table with possible inputs on the left column and the evaluation of all the possible outcomes of the proposition as whole:

[image: The input on the left and the outcome on the right.]

To conclude:
We have a non composed proposition which is a single statement which can either be True or False.

We have a composed proposition without connectives which can have different possible inputs for True or False, yet the result of the statement depends on the input True or false.

We have composed propositions which are multiple propositions that are chained together using logical connectives. For each distinct non composed proposition we have can have input True or False. The chaining of these values will eventualy result in either True or False for the proposition as a whole depending on the given input values.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the question is "How do we think of propositions as sets?"  Your answer doesn't seem to actually address this question at all.

Comment: i was trying to explain how a non composed prop is basically a singleton set with element: { Q } with the set of { T, F } being the ways describing the same statement as equivalence prop. Yet when we create a composed prop of 1 define prop in combination with connectives we end up with a prop which can seen as a set which contains al non composed propositions and all used propositions with connectives ( the top row of a truth table } given that set and the combination of T F for non composed propositions we could restructur our composed proposition using the rules of logical equivalence.